# Chromecast android app promotion

Tags: android, chromecast, promoting

I plan to publish an android application which makes use of the Chromecast.
(i) Does Google promote these kind of applications?
(ii) Is there a list of Chromecast apps in the playstore where I can list it?

Comment: I don't betleive so, unless it becomes popular.

Comment: This is not a technical question, please ask this question on our Google Cast Developers G+ community: https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/115742157569103585450

Answer (score 1):

From the Chromecast application, in the nav drawer, there's an "Applications" entry, which opens the Play Store. Here you have a list of Cast-compatible promoted apps.